# how do we compare 2 class names of an object

Tags: objective-c, class, comparison, object

Is there a way to get compare class name betweeen 2 objects?

Like:

```
NSString *bla = [[NSString alloc] init];
if([bla class] isEqual: NSString])
 NSLog(@"success");
```

unsure if my syntax is correct.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Correct syntax is:

```
if ([bla class] == [NSString class])
```

You can also use `-isMemberOfClass:` or -`isKindOfClass:` messages from [`NSObject` protocol](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000052-DontLinkElementID_5).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/16424298/1445366 for cases in which this won't work.

Answer (score 11):

This should do it:

```
NSString *bla = [[NSString alloc] init];
if ( [bla isMemberOfClass: [NSString class]] == YES )
     NSLog(@"Success");
```

Comment: Of course, `== YES` is optional. It probably looks better without it too!

Comment: In fact, comparing your BOOLs to YES is a bad idea. The BOOL type is not constrained to YES and NO, and some methods return a BOOL that is neither.

Comment: What methods return a `BOOL` that is neither?

Comment: @Wevah: I wish I could remember, but it's been too long. They might actually have been fixed by now for all I know. At any rate, it's safer and no more difficult to test `something != NO` (and, of course, this is the check that an if-statement naturally performs, so it can be omitted in that context).