# Why is [@"" class] != NSClassFromString(NSStringFromClass([@"" class])) on OS X?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, operating-system

```
if([@"" class] == NSClassFromString(NSStringFromClass([@"" class])))
    printf("foo");
else
    printf("bar");
```

Output on iOS: foo

Output on OS X: bar

Why is this behaving that strange on OS X?

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger or logging to determine what the results of `NSStringFromClass` and `NSClassFromString` are?

Comment: I would guess that `[@"" class]` could (conceptually) have any several different values, depending on whether the NSString is constructed, statically defined, etc.  Cocoa loves to have multiple internal classes for the same external one, and likely these are different between iOS and OSx.

Comment: I've got 'foo' on OS X and on iOS. Both strings are the same private class of `__NSCFConstantString`. And use `NSLog();` instead of `printf();`

Comment: @Kri: Yes, I have stepped through with the debugger and looked at the overlays, when storing them in variables and the funny thing is: [@"" class] and NSClassFromString(NSStringFromClass([@"" class])) both show up as __NSCFConstantString on both OS, so they look like having identical values also on OS X.

Comment: @Tom: Hmm, I have even copied the code into a brand new empty test project, that I have just created from the OS X Foundation command line tool template and I still get bar.
I have tried with debug and release config, 32 and 64 bit and different base SDKs and target platforms, but it always bar for OS X.
Can you tell me the settings for which you have got foo, please?

Comment: @Kaiserludi, iOS Project has Base SDK: Latest iOS (iOS 6.1), project made for iPhone. OS X Project is set for Mountain Lion. That's all. MBP 2010, Xcode 4.6.2

Comment: The docs specifically state that the different ways to get a class may return different pointers. I'll see if I can find it later if no one else has.

Comment: @ughoavgfhw - I was looking as I thought the docs said the opposite somewhere... All I've found so far is <http://tinyurl.com/c2c342s> but it doesn't really say either way, however the first code sample uses `==` to compare Class values... Also ARC treats Class values specially and does not retain them, but doesn't mean they are unique just immortal. But why have two immortal objects to represent the same thing? We must also consider it may be a bug since fixed (its works in at least 10.8.3) So please report what you find to satisfy our curiosity!

Comment: @CRD That link uses `==` to compare values which were retrieved similarly (both from calling methods). What I was thinking of specifically stated that getting it different ways (e.g. `-class` and `NSClassFromString`) could have different results. Anyway (@Everyone), I couldn't find it. I did find that the KVO docs still mention [their implementation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOImplementation.html), which was one source of the discrepancy. But that really only affects `isa`, so its possible things have changed.

Answer (score 9):

Interesting issue. The following points out some things mentioned in the comments:

```
Class c1 = [@"" class];
Class c2 = NSClassFromString(NSStringFromClass([@"" class]));

// The names are the same under iOS and OS X
NSLog(@"c1: '%@', c2: '%@'", c1, c2);
// The pointers are the same under iOS but different under OS X
NSLog(@"*c1: '%p', *c2: '%p'", c1, c2);

if (c1 == c2) {
    NSLog(@"== equal"); // iOS
} else {
    NSLog(@"== not equal"); // OS X
}

if ([c1 isEqual:c2]) {
    NSLog(@"isEqual: equal"); // iOS
} else {
    NSLog(@"isEqual: not equal"); // OS X
}

const char *n1 = class_getName(c1);
const char *n2 = class_getName(c2);
if (strcmp(n1, n2) == 0) {
    NSLog(@"name equal"); // Both iOS and OS X
} else {
    NSLog(@"name not equal");
}
```

On a Mac (OS X 10.7.5) this gives:

> 2013-05-07 12:35:45.249 Test[27483:303] c1: '_*NSCFConstantString', c2: '*_NSCFConstantString'
>   2013-05-07 12:40:06.673 Test[27542:303] *c1: '0x7fff7d2bd740', *c2: '0x7fff7d28ae48'
>   2013-05-07 12:35:45.250 Test[27483:303] == not equal
>   2013-05-07 12:35:45.251 Test[27483:303] isEqual: not equal
>   2013-05-07 12:35:45.251 Test[27483:303] name equal

On iOS (6.1) this gives:

> 2013-05-07 12:38:11.816 Test[27516:11303] c1: '_*NSCFConstantString', c2: '*_NSCFConstantString'
>   2013-05-07 12:41:01.319 Test[27557:11303] *c1: '0x1db88f8', *c2: '0x1db88f8'
>   2013-05-07 12:38:11.816 Test[27516:11303] == equal
>   2013-05-07 12:38:11.816 Test[27516:11303] isEqual: equal
>   2013-05-07 12:38:11.816 Test[27516:11303] name equal

The key difference seems to be that under iOS, the two `Class` values are the same object but under OS X they are two different objects.

So it seems it is not safe to compare two `Class` values using `==` or `isEqual:`, at least under OS X. I couldn't find any function to compare two `Class` values so using `class_getName` seems like the best alternative.

Comment: I get the same classes (identical pointers) on OS X (as Tomasz Szulc reported in his comment to the question).

Comment: I should have pointed out that I ran my test under OS X 10.7.5 (Lion). It appears the results in 10.8.x are different than with 10.7.x.

Comment: Use isKindOf: to compare to NSString. Remember NSString is a class cluster.

Comment: @uchuugaka Where in this code are `NSString` values being compared? `isKindOf:` is used to see if one class is the same as another class or one of its subclasses. It's not used with strings. Since the goal here was to see if the two classes represent the same class (on not a possible subclass), then `isKindOf:` isn't appropriate.

Comment: Then use `isMemberOfClass:`.

Comment: @RobNapier But that's the easy way and would negate the whole point to the OP question. :)

Comment: To the point of the question, however, the reason is simple: Classes are objects, and it is possible to have more than one instance. And it's even possible for classes to masquerade as other classes (KVO classes do it all the time) such that they are completely distinct but appear the same. You can't use `==` to compare objects to anything but themselves. That said, I am actually a little surprised that `isEqual:` fails, but then Classes are objects, but not *exactly* objects in ObjC. :D They're kind of object-like.

Comment: (I'm not saying anything that hasn't already been said a couple of times in other comments; just kind of summing it up.)

Comment: @RobNapier - Classes *are* objects as you say, so surely we should at least be a bit more than a little surprised when `isEqual:` returns false... but looking at the code it does ptr comparison - why would Apple use pointer comparison for Class's `isEqual:`? Furthermore `isMemberOf:` calls `class` and then does ptr comparison. The expectation of many, including Apple (see ref in Q comments), is that Class objects are unique per type, and so ptr comparison is OK between them. And if `isEqual:` and `isMemberOf:` also fail what to use? So bug or not? Just curious :-)

Comment: @rmaddy sorry I though my grammar was clear. isKindOf: to compare to NSString. I did not say to compare two instances of NSString. I say to use isKindOf: because the classes that make up the class cluster are private and should not be compared directly as they can change without notice from Apple, but they should respond to isKindOf: