# May I use == or != to compare [aClass class] with [bClass class]?

Tags: objective-c, class

```
if ([aClass class] == [bClass class]) {

}
```

or

```
if ([[aClass class] isEqual:[bClass class]]) {

}
```

if not, why?

Comment: See also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424298/why-is-class-nsclassfromstringnsstringfromclass-class-on-os-x

Comment: those are structure
you can use if([someObject isKindOfClass:[NSManagedObject class]]){}

Comment: @DevanshuSaini You wouldn't want to use `isKindOfClass` here. `isMemberOfClass` would be better.

Comment: are `aClass` and `bClass` pointers to class objects? or pointers to instances?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `isMemberOfClass` to check both object belong to same class like this

```
if ([aClas isMemberOfClass:class] && [bClas isMemberOfClass:class]) {

}
```

Comment: This is incorrect. `isKindOfClass` checks to see if the receiver is an instance of class or an instance of any class that inherits from class.

Comment: You both are right :-).  Consider for example case when actual class is not an NSString but __NSCFString. From the developer' point of view they are the same. But technically they belong to different classes.

Comment: @ВладимирВодолазкий That's not an example of what I was referring to. Let's say `aClas` is `UIView` and `bClas` is `UIControl`. And lastly `class` is `UIResponder`. The `if` statement in this answer will be true but clearly `aClas` and `bClas` are not the same.

Comment: @maddy OK, I agree, but to propagate this approach we can just use NSObject as base to compare. The key to success lies in properly chosen class.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks for suggestion, edited the answer using `isMemberOfClass`.

Comment: @ВладимирВодолазкий You are missing the point. The original question is about seeing if two objects are of the same class. I was pointing out that using `isKindOfClass` was wrong. The key to success lies in performing the proper check to see if both classes are the same, not in properly choosing the class.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, class objects can always be compared with physical equality (`==`, `!=`). There is always going to be one class object for each class. Two different class objects are never going to be "equal".